# Large data with Spark and CouchDB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, couchdb, cloudant, apache-bahir

I used spark 2.4.0 with "org.apache.bahir - spark-sql-cloudant - 2.4.0"
I have to download all json files from couchDB to hdfs.

```
 val df = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.bahir.cloudant")
  .load("demo")
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

 df
  .write
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
  .mode("append")
  .parquet("...")
```

Total file size is 160GB (> 13 millions files)
Spark job after 5 minutes running gets error

> Caused by: com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Error retrieving server response

Increasing the timeout does not help, falls off but later
What are the ways out of the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Use another endpoint for queries, use  **_changes**  against **_all_docs** helped me